# Is the conjugate axis in hyperbola just a number?

Tags: conic-sections

My maths teacher is teaching hyperbola these days, and when he drew the hyperbola, I was not able to see $b$ (in $\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$) in the graph. When I asked about it, all he did was just marked the points $(0,b)$ and $(0,-b)$. I expected a lot more, but sir just said $b$ according to him has an indirect significance ($a^2+b^2=(ae)^2$). I'm still not satisfied. Is $b$ just a number?

Comment: Right, $b$ is just a number. Also, the "hyperbolic geometry" tag doesn't apply here.

Comment: The asymptotes of the hyperbola are $\frac{x}{a} \pm \frac{y}{b} = 0$, aka $y = \pm\frac{b}{a} x$. That is, the asymptotes are the extended diagonals of the origin-centered rectangle with "semi-width" $a$ and "semi-height" $b$.

Comment: BTW: Here's a bit more on the geometry of the hyperbola and the relation $a^2+b^2=c^2$ from the *conic section* interpretation of the hyperbola: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/409149/409