# Dandelin spheres and the asymptotes of a hyperbola

Tags: euclidean-geometry, conic-sections

The other day, I was reading up on the synthetic geometry of conic sections a bit, and I wondered: is it possible to construct the hyperbola's asymptotes given just the intersecting plane and the Dandelin spheres? Are the asymptotes and the Dandelin spheres connected in any non-trivial/interesting way? I know there's a fairly obvious connection between the spheres and the hyperbola's foci and directrices.

Thanks!

Comment: Of course, Dandelin spheres tell you everything. The set of lines *internally* tangent to both spheres is the cone itself. Each line *externally* tangent to both spheres is the axis of a hyperbola in the plane tangent to the cone along that line (and each of these hyperbolas has the same shape). So, it's possible to express various metric properties of a conic section ---in particular, the slopes of the asymptotes--- in terms of the radii and separation distance of its Dandelin spheres. The algebra can be a bit tedious; I don't know off-hand if the resulting formulas are particularly nice.

Comment: It's worth noting that, if a plane $p$ cuts a cone to make a hyperbola, then the plane $p^\prime$ ---parallel to $p$ and passing through the vertex of the cone--- cuts the cone in two lines that "look like" the hyperbola's asymptotes. (The lines make the same angle as the asymptotes, but they aren't "centered" in space with the hyperbola itself.) BTW, [this answer to a vaguely-related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/409149/409) discusses a relation using Dandelin spheres of hyperbolas for which the "cutting plane" is parallel to the cone axis.

Comment: Thanks, Blue; that's very interesting. I'll try and prove the property of your plane $p'$.

Comment: To prove the property of $p^\prime$, derive formulas based on a plane $p$ that cuts the cone axis at some distance ---say, $d$--- from the cone's vertex. You'll find that formula for the slopes of the asymptotes is independent of $d$.