# Can this equation $b^2$ = $c^2-a^2$ be derived intuitively?

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

Today while proving the equation of hyperbolas,$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1\tag{1}$$ I came across this expression $$b^2=c^2-a^2\tag 2$$ Though this expression seems much like Pythagorean Theorem, I couldn't find any relation between the two (sorry for that). I'm using my math textbook to prove the hyperbola equation but even there nothing is mentioned about that "Pythagorean-like" equation. It's simply written there.

[image]

My question is :

Could you please give me an intuitive proof of that equation? I don't need the full hyperbola proof. I'll work it out myself. Just want to know how is the equation in $(2)$ derived.

P.S-I know a healthy bit of geometry so you can use it in your answers.

Comment: So is $c$ half the distance between the foci, as suggested by the diagram?

Comment: Related (duplicate?): ["A geometric reason why the square of the focal length of a hyperbola is equal to the sum of the squares of the axes?"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/408954/409)

Comment: Potentially useful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Hyperbel-param-e.svg .  Of course the slope of the asymptote is $b/a$.  The interesting thing to prove is that the point on the circle (centered at M with radius reaching to both foci) gives coordinates $a$ and $b$.  Used here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbola#Asymptotes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From focus $F_2$ draw a perpendicular to $x$-axis, to intersect the hyperbola at $P=(c,y)$. By definition we know that $PF_1=y+2a$, hence by Pythagoras' theorem:
$$
(y+2a)^2=y^2+(2c)^2,
\quad\text{that is:}\quad
y={c^2-a^2\over a}.
$$
Inserting then the coordinates of $P$ into the hyperbola equation gives:
$$
{c^2\over a^2}-{(c^2-a^2)^2\over a^2b^2}=1,
\quad\text{that is:}\quad
c^2-a^2=b^2.
$$

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot but should we use use the hyperbola equation to prove $b^2=c^2-a^2$. I'm curious because in my book this equation is used while proving the hyperbola equation.

Comment: You should then tell exactly how your book introduces $b$. Usually, $b$ is *defined* by $b^2=c^2-a^2$, and later on one recognises that lines $y=\pm b/a$ are asypmptotic to the hyperbola, thus giving $b$ a more concrete meaning.

Comment: It's just introduced as such referring to the diagram which I have drawn like "We define $b=\sqrt{c^2-a^2}$ "

Comment: And yes, the asymptotes are drawn but nothing is written about them. That's my book please refer to page 257  https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=2ahUKEwjqp93P343hAhXNfCsKHd9yCUkQFjAAegQIAhAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ncert.nic.in%2Fncerts%2Fl%2Fkemh111.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2emP8DqKEyhcXl7YMZCpsz

Comment: So $b$ is defined by $b^2=c^2-a^2$, but for an hyperbola its geometric meaning is less obvious. It is connected to the asymptotes, and also to the *latus rectum* ($PF_2$ in my answer) which is $b^2/a$.

Comment: Thanks a lot...got it...