# How can I prove that $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$ in a hyperbola?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, conic-sections

I have a question about hyperbolas as follows.

Given this basic diagram of a hyperbola, with points $a, b, c$ (and their negatives respectively), how can I prove the fundamental formula $a^2 + b ^2 = c^2 $ geometrically (in terms of $a, b,$ and $c$) and be able to explain it to my math teacher and class (high school sophomores in PreCalculus). [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xq4mq.jpg) My difficulty lies in how the line from $(0,b)$ to $(a,0)$ [shown in light blue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3dZ3.jpg) is the same as $(c,0)$ [also shown in light blue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8qOB.jpg).

Best,
A PreCalculus Student

Comment: You must tell us how $a,b,c$ is defined in your class, otherwise we will not know which definition of hyperbola you are using.

Comment: @StAKmod a is the centre, b is a point defined in the picture (I'm actually not sure what it is called, and c is the foci on the positive x side of the graph.

Comment: It appears that $\pm b/a$ are the slopes of the asymptotes

Comment: Related (duplicate?): [A geometric reason why the square of the focal length of a hyperbola is equal to the sum of the squares of the axes?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/408954/409)