# A way to directly see $a^2+b^2=f^2$ for hyperbolae?

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, conic-sections, visualization

with focal length $f$ and $a,b$ from the standard equation (up-down opening, origin centered):
$$ \frac{y^2}{a^2} - \frac{x^2}{b^2} = 1 $$

Using the definition that a hyperbola is the points whose distance from two points (*focii*) differ by a constant, the standard equation can be obtained, with $f^2-a^2$ in place of $b^2$ --- which rearranges to $a^2+b^2=f^2$.

It seems that $b$ is invented to make a nice standard form. Does it have 
geometric significance?

The $a^2+b^2=f^2$ equation itself has the form of the Pythagorean Theorem... but in a hyperbola $a,b,f$ do not measure the sides of a right triangle!  Instead, $f$ is the distance from the center to each *focii*; $a$ is the distance from the center to the *vertices*; and $b$ does not appear to have a geometric representation. Far from forming a right triangle, the line segments measured by $a,f$ are colinear.

Is there an interpretation of $a$, $b$ and $f$ as a right triangle?

EDIT We can use the complex plane to get an intersection when $y=0$ (as for an ellipse), at $(ib,0)$. The distance between the x-axis and y-axis intersections (vertices) is $f$.

Though I don't see how that particular segment, of length $f$, has any geometric significance in itself.

Comment: $b$ measures the length of the conjugate semi-axis. Also, the asymptotes of the hyperbola pass through the vertices of a $2a\times 2b$ rectangle whose center matches the hyperbola's center and whose edges are parallel to the hyperbola's axes.

Comment: See also this (possibly duplicate) question: ["A geometric reason why the square of the focal length of a hyperbola is equal to the sum of the squares of the axes?"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/408954/409). Perhaps in particular, [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/409149/409).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Hyperbel-param-e.svg

Comment: Thanks @Blue! I agree we can draw a right triangle with those lengths, but it does not seem related to the hyperbola. The only conection I see is that the asymptote has exactlty the right slope, $a/b$. But why have the focal length along that slope? Why call $b$ the length of the conjugate semi-axis? It seems to me the only reason is to form that synthetic right triangle, to construct an artificial geometrical interpretation of the $a^2+b^2=f^2$ equation... Sorry, I don't mean to be critical, it's just that that's the very thing I'm struggling with! Though it is a good way to remember it.

Comment: @hyperpallium: That's why I linked to the other question. :)

Comment: @Blue I had a quick look at your answer, and those Dandelin spheres seem promising, but will require careful study!

Comment: A very good reason to call it the conjugate semiaxis length is because it is. That is, it’s the transverse semiaxis length of the conjugate hyperbola $y^2/b^2-x^2/a^2=1$.

Comment: @amd Thanks, and maybe gives legitimacy for defining $b$, because the simple variation yielding the conjugate hyperbola does have a vertex there. Or is it only a "simple variation" in this specific standard *form*, which assumes this definitiin of $b$? Or are conjugate hyperbolae natural, indepedent of this form?

Comment: Every hyperbola has a conjugate. In the general case, its equation isn’t as easy to derive, but the equations can always be put into standard form via a suitable rigid motion of the plane.

Comment: The equation of any hyperbola with asymptotes $lx+my+n=0$ and $px+qy+r=0$ can be written in the form $(lx+my+n)(px+qy+r)=k$. In this form, the conjugate is obtained by replacing $k$ with $-k$.

Comment: @Blue Thought of a way to think about the curve of a hyperbola; don't know if it helps: draw a circle at a focus, touching the nearest vertex. Draw a (much larger) circle at the other focus, touching the *same* vertex. These circles fully account for the difference in distances to them (so that that vertex satisfies the rule, and is part of the hyperbola). Now... to maintain that constant difference, we need to move away from both cirxles equally. So further points on that curve are equidistant from both circles (radially). This makes it easier to picture the curve (and maybe understand it?)